# Positioning the image and text in same lane

Tags: positioning, cv

I'm trying to create a CV with Latex but I'm having a hard time while positioning the pictures and texts. What I want to obtain is on the right but what happens is in the left. I just want to put the text and picture where i want, independently from each other.
[image]

And here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

%tcolorbox for the formatting
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%geometry package for margins, locations etc.
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0cm,
    right=0cm,
    top=0cm,
%   bottom=0.1cm
}

%color of title
\definecolor{titleBack}{RGB}{224,220,220}

%title
\title{John Doe}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{colframe=titleBack,colback=titleBack,arc=0mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
        \hspace*{-0.3cm}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{mypicture.eps}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{15cm}
        \begin{center}
            \Huge{\textcolor{black}{John Doe}} \\
            \vspace*{0.5cm}
            \Large{\textcolor{black}{\emph{Computer Engineering Student}}}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two suggestions: Either try to put it in a tabular environment with two columns or use package multicols and put it into these.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I put the version that i fixed in answers?

Comment: To get the expected output, just remove the empty line between the two minipage environments.

Comment: Thank you! That do the job too. Can you explain why is like this?

Comment: Adding an epmty line between minipages causes the second minipage to be placed in its own paragraph, so the text containing minipage ends up below the image insted of next to it. For side by side minipages, make sure, there is no empty line inbetween.